# Bing and google blocked in windows firewall, still gets through

Tags: networking, firewall, blocking

I have a set of computers here where I need to block google and bing. I ping google.com and bing.com which return some IP address that I add to my blocked windows firewall rules. Pinging these websites again gives me "general failure". However, after a few minutes the websites become accessible again, even though ping still returns general failure.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Because like most major websites google and bing have fail-over, meaning they have multiple IP addresses for each domain. Its like when one road is blocked for construction in town, but you can still go home by taking a different road. If you want to block these websites try entering the URL aka google.com or bing.com into the firewall, you might even try `*.google.*` which would block out of country blocked sites and all sub-domains for google. this should allow the firewall to block all fail-over addresses that the DNS knows.

If you are still having issues remember that Windows firewall is not the "best" firewall at blocking all traffic. If you can I would recommend either buying a dedicated firewall (if possible) or getting different firewall software that has more features.

**UPDATE 1:**

This might make more sense for what fail-over is and how it works

http://social.dnsmadeeasy.com/blog/dnscoach/dns-failover-work/

As for the original question you can also use the hosts file to block domains as listed above
    `(*.google.*)`
and it is easy to reverse. The info is found below on how to do this.

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/block-websites-using-hosts-file/

Comment: Unfortunately windows firewall can't block by hostname. I'm a bit confused as to why the command "ping google.com" would resolve to the same IP address every time but the web browser would go to a different IP.

Comment: @D.Johnson - In the simplest terms, Google uses a load balancer.  when you perform a ping you receive a response from that part of Google's network.  When you actually navigate to their domain address using a different protocol other devices take over.  A full explanation is outside the scope of a comment, and wouldn't answer the question, as it's currently written.